# Android TextView type not working

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Working on an example project and (I'm a complete newbie with Java and Android) need to declare a couple vars as 'TextView'

So, in the imports section I have:

`import android.widget.TextView;`

and so I declare thusly:

`private TextView myViewVar;`

Only, TextView is NOT highlighted as a TYPE and the app crashes when it attempts to use it.
I downloaded the Android-18 SDK with the Eclipse IDE SDK manager without incident.

Am I missing some other magic here?

Comment: magic??? yeah!!?.. its avada kedavra!!! .. lol.. to be b serious elaborate futher on your error, maybe with codes or logcat

Comment: What error message are you getting when your app crashes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare your textView like this:

```
myViewVar = new TextView(this);
```

or like this:

```
myViewVar = (TextView) findViewById(R.Id.yourid);
```

before using it.

You should also declare the TextView in a XML file.

Comment: Thanks Robbe :-)  As it turns out, my familiarity with Visual Studio worked against me when using Eclipse - expected the TextView type to get syntactical highlighting. It was working, app was crashing b/c of missing permission.